# Jquery dropdown prevent duplicate

Tags: html, jquery

I want to somehow prevent duplicate in my dropdown menu. So I have an input field where user can type something,then that will be saved in an dropdown menu. But I want to make sure that there will never be created a duplicate somehow. I have looked everywhere for days, and I can't find the right answer. I hope someone can help me.

This is what it looks like right now

[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+unique+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: `const drop = []; function getInput() { const val = input.value; if (!drop.includes(val)) { drop.push(val); renderDropDown()); } }`

Comment: Check if the select already contains the values by looping through the select options and seeing if it's the same value.  If one is found don't add new value (or, only add new value if one is not found), example: `if $("select>option").filter((i,e)=>e.innerText === inp).length === 0) { ... add new value inp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
                $(".dropdown > option").each(function(i){
                if ($(this).val() == $("#addforfatter").val()) {
                $(this).remove();
            }});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).